# Ubuntu Gitosis init web folder

Tags: git, gitosis

I managed to setup gitosis on Ubuntu, authorization done using SSH keys. Now I want to make some folders on this Ubuntu server Git Initialized and available thrue gitosis. For example `/var/www/x1 folder`. It is web page I'm working on, and would like to see changes made available public (this is `/var/www` example for .. or simbolic link).

Gitosis created his folder structure in `/srv/gitosis/repositories/`. I expected to see files which I commited/pushed on server in this folder, but there is only some weird file structure made.

I hope someone understood what i was trying to ask. Hoping for some quick and easy fix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably seeing is a bare repository.
A regular repository is a working directory with a `.git` folder that contains all the tracking information. Bare repositories however are designed for servers that you only want to push and pull from, they're just a folder containing what would normally be in the `.git` folder.

Try manually creating a git repo with a simple `git init` and see if Gitosis will work with that.